# Get JavaScript value from code behind vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I want to pass my JavaScript value – latitude and longitude – to the code behind vb.net. I have tried to use `document.getElementById("<%=hdn.ClientID%>").value` to pass the value, but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="hdn"/>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

document.getElementById("<%=hdn.ClientID%>").value = x.innerHTML;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Code behind

```
Dim location As String = hdn.Value
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is probably working. However, your code behind will not have access to the new hidden field data until it does another post. This is because the javascript is running client side. The code behind is server side.

As a test add a ASP button, click on it and then check your field.

This is my script:

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
            "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

        document.getElementById('hdn').value = x.innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

This is my html:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Refresh" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Position" ></asp:Label>
        <br />
        </div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" ValidateRequestMode="Disabled" />
</form>
```

Comment: I edited my answer with added code examples.